# urlencode/urldecode problem

Tags: php

I am selecting data from a MySql database and doing the following

```
echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"distadd1\" id=\"distadd1\" class=\"textbox\" value=".  urlencode($row['ADD1']). " >";
```

however the value is being displayed as follows Department+of+Planning+%26+Development.

how do i remove the + and %26

Comment: Why are you urlencoding the value in the first place?

Comment: I would think to prevent XSS/script injection

Comment: I want to place the string 'Add1' into the Form Input Box,
If I just say     $row['ADD1']
I get the first word of the string, in this case Department
but I found by using urlencode I displayed the whole string but with the spacial characters.

I'm new to PHP and may be trying to do this wrong.

Comment: What special characters? Consider htmlentities().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

URL encoding is different than what you want to do it sounds like.  Try changing URL encode to htmlentities, which will get rid of the '+' and the &26; but will still protect you from XSS / script injection into your webpages.

```
Example #1 A htmlentities() example
<?php
$str = "A 'quote' is <b>bold</b>";

// Outputs: A 'quote' is &lt;b&gt;bold&lt;/b&gt;
echo htmlentities($str);

// Outputs: A &#039;quote&#039; is &lt;b&gt;bold&lt;/b&gt;
echo htmlentities($str, ENT_QUOTES);
?>
```

From the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)

Comment: I tried htmlentities but it just returns the first word of the string.

Comment: what is your actual HTML output (not what is rendered through the browser)?

Comment: your reference to htmlentities help me find the problem.

it  was simply value=". "\"" . $row['ADD1']."\"". " >";

ie surround the variable with double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Don't add those symbols in the first place. The urlencode() function, as its name suggests, is used to generate URLs. You probably want to use htmlspecialchars().

> I tried htmlentities but it just
>   returns the first word of the string.

Your HTML is invalid. You need to use quotes so your attributes can contain spaces. Compare:

```
<input name=user value=foo bar id=foo>
<input name="user" value="foo bar" id="foo">
```